# как в конструкции switch-case указать несколько значений для одного case?

Tags: javascript, php, c

Есть к примеру следующий код:(пример на Си)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        switch(i) {
            case 1 ... 3:
                printf("some text\n");
                break;
            case 0: case 4:
                continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не помню где я узнал про `...` но в `switch case` с его помощью можно указать диапазон последовательных значений, как в моем случае от 1 до 3 включительно.

Есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива этому `...` в языках `JavaScript` и `PHP`? Если да то какая?

Comment: Такие диапазоны, это все же не "классический" C. Вроде бы в каком-то из расширений для GCC так можно делать. Не думаю что в PHP или Javascript есть подобные конструкции. Это слишком сложно для интерпретации. Особенно если учитывать что эти языки не строготипизированы как C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В **javaScript** в явном виде такого сделать нельзя, кроме как перечислять кейсы друг за другом

```
switch(data) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
    // code
    break;
  case 4:
  case 5:
  ...
}
```

Однако можно использовать фукнции :)

> в сравнении **case** указать фукнцию, в которую передаем проверяемое значение

Главное, что бы функция вернула то же значение, что и пришло, при успешной проверке данных, т.к. в case будет сравниваться переданное значение с результатом фукнции и результат сравнения должен быть **true**

```js
function swither(data) {
  switch (data) {
    case checker(data):
      console.log(1)
      break;
    case checker2(data):
      console.log(2)
      break
    default:
      console.log(3)
  }
}

function checker(res) {
  const responses = [1,2,3];
  return responses.includes(res) ? res : {}
}

function checker2(res) {
  const responses = [4,5,6];
  return responses.includes(res) ? res : {}
}

swither(1)
swither(2)
swither(4)
swither(5)
swither(7)
swither(8)
```

Или вот так:

> в **switch** передать уже обработанные(сгруппированные) данные по какому то условию

```js
function swither(data) {
  switch (checker(data)) {
    case 1:
      console.log(1)
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log(2)
      break;
    default:
      console.log(3)
  }
}

function checker(res) {
  const responses = [1,2,3];
  return responses.includes(res) ? 1 : 2
}

swither(1)
swither(2)
swither(4)
swither(5)
swither(7)
swither(8)
```

Почему в случае не совпадения передается объект, потому что 2 разных объекта не равны друг другу

```js
console.log({} === {})
console.log([] === [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно зачем это нужно, так как не очень явно, да и наверное очень редко такое бывает, когда совпадают несколько case.

Но если очень хочется, то можно например вот так

```php
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo("I = " . $i . " -> ");
        switch(true) {
            case in_array($i, range(1,3)):
                echo("some text");
                break;
            case ($i === 0 || $i === 4):
                echo("other text");
                break;
        }
    echo("\n");
}
```

Основной момент тут что в **switch** стоит *true*, условия проверяются в **case**. Не очень очевидный ход. Если есть цель запутать того, кто будет поддерживать ваш код, то метод самое то.

Если желаная запутать нет, то наверное правильнее такие вещи кодировать через `if ... elseif ... elseif ... else ...`

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем диапазоны, но можно указывать несколько `case`-ов подряд:

```
switch (5) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        console.log("some text");
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
        console.log("other text");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("default");
        break;
}
```

UPD. А, заметил, что в вашем примере на C это тоже используется (`case 0: case 4:`).